# Giving an erroneous answer for my if statement

Tags: c++

The problem is my code is giving a wrong answer when the user inputs less than 40 hours worked .It is supposed to use the statement (max_Minimum_Pay = hours_Worked * MINIMUM_PAY_RATE)but instead it looks like its skipping over that and multiplying 0.10 * sales amount?

```
//Declaring variables//
    double hours_Worked;
    double sales_Amount;
    double overtime_Hours;
    double overtime_Pay;
    double reg_Minimum_Pay {};
    double commission_Percentage;
    double commission_Pay;
    double max_Minimum_Pay;
    double const onePercent_Commission = 0.01;
    double const twoPercent_Commission = 0.02;
    double const threePercent_Commission = 0.03;
    double const fourPercent_Commission = 0.04;
    double const OVERTIME_THRESHOLD = 40.0;
    double const OVERTIME_PAY_MULTIPLIER = 1.50; 
    double const  MINIMUM_PAY_RATE = 15.00;



//Get Hours worked and sales amount//
    cout << "How many hours did you work this week?";
    cin >> hours_Worked;
    cout << "How much money did you makes this week in sales? ";
    cin >> sales_Amount;

//Displays error message if user inputs a negative number for sales amount and hours worked//
    if (hours_Worked < 0 || sales_Amount < 0)
        cout << "Error:Must be more than 0";

//Determines if the user reached the Overtime pay threshold//
//calculates minimum wage, including overtime pay if eligible//
    if (hours_Worked <= OVERTIME_THRESHOLD)
        max_Minimum_Pay = hours_Worked * MINIMUM_PAY_RATE;
    else
        
        
        reg_Minimum_Pay = OVERTIME_THRESHOLD * MINIMUM_PAY_RATE;
        overtime_Hours = hours_Worked - OVERTIME_THRESHOLD;
        overtime_Pay = (OVERTIME_PAY_MULTIPLIER * MINIMUM_PAY_RATE) * overtime_Hours;
        max_Minimum_Pay = overtime_Pay + reg_Minimum_Pay;
        
        
//Determines what percentage is used for weekly commission calculation based on weekly sales amount//
        if (sales_Amount < 5000)
            commission_Percentage = onePercent_Commission;
        else if (sales_Amount >= 5000 && sales_Amount < 10000)
                    commission_Percentage = twoPercent_Commission;
        else if (sales_Amount >= 10000 && sales_Amount < 20000)
                    commission_Percentage = threePercent_Commission;
        else if(sales_Amount>=20000)
                commission_Percentage = fourPercent_Commission;
//Calculates weekly commission pay//
        commission_Pay = sales_Amount * commission_Percentage;
//Determines if commission pay is greater than minimum wage pay or not //
        if (commission_Pay > max_Minimum_Pay)
            cout << commission_Pay;
        else
            cout << max_Minimum_Pay;
```

Comment: Please focus your question on your immediate issue. There is (likely) no need to tell us the problem you are solving. (You might want to tell us that it is a homework problem, but the details are at best a footnote, not the opening salvo.) Create a [mre] by trimming down the code to just the problematic lines, plus necessary variable definitions. Use something like `double hours_Worked = 30.0;` instead of relying on user input. Focus and simplify!

Comment: How many statements are you expecting to be executed by the `else` clause of `if (hours_Worked <= OVERTIME_THRESHOLD)`? If you want/hope it will be more than one (the calculation of `reg_Minimum_Pay`), then you need to learn about braces to "group" multiple statements: `if (...) { ... } else { ... }`.

Comment: Unlike some languages `c++` does not use indentation to indicate scope. You need to use { and } to form a scope after the else. With this said we as programmers often indent our scopes, but that is for readability the c++ compiler ignores the indentation.

Comment: Use braces for the if/else blocks. If you don't use them it only executes one line of code in each part, yet you're indentation seems to imply that a whole bunch of code should execute on the else blocks.

Comment: Unlike python, C++ doesn't care about indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want all the lines after the `else` to be executed only in case `hours_Worked > OVERTIME_THRESHOLD` here:

```
    if (hours_Worked <= OVERTIME_THRESHOLD)
        max_Minimum_Pay = hours_Worked * MINIMUM_PAY_RATE;
    else             
        reg_Minimum_Pay = OVERTIME_THRESHOLD * MINIMUM_PAY_RATE;
        overtime_Hours = hours_Worked - OVERTIME_THRESHOLD;
        overtime_Pay = (OVERTIME_PAY_MULTIPLIER * MINIMUM_PAY_RATE) * overtime_Hours;
        max_Minimum_Pay = overtime_Pay + reg_Minimum_Pay;
        ...
```

This is however not what happens. The last three lines above will be executed no matter what the condition result is. If you want more than one line to only be executed if the `if` condition is `false`, create a scope with `{` ... `}`:

```
    if (hours_Worked <= OVERTIME_THRESHOLD)
        max_Minimum_Pay = hours_Worked * MINIMUM_PAY_RATE;
    else {            
        reg_Minimum_Pay = OVERTIME_THRESHOLD * MINIMUM_PAY_RATE;
        overtime_Hours = hours_Worked - OVERTIME_THRESHOLD;
        overtime_Pay = (OVERTIME_PAY_MULTIPLIER * MINIMUM_PAY_RATE) * overtime_Hours;
        max_Minimum_Pay = overtime_Pay + reg_Minimum_Pay;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Additional reading on the topic: [Compound Statements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Compound_statements)